# Curl give Result Fail

Tags: php

I am working on server side in php. initially testing this code:

```
    $apiKey = "";


$registrationIDs = array( "" );


$message = "hello";


$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';


$fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),

                );


$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'

                );



$ch = curl_init();


$u=curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );


$p=curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

$f=curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$h=curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$t=curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

$c=curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$j=curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );


$result = curl_exec($ch);

 $responseInfo    = curl_getinfo($ch);
   $header_size    = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE); 
   $responseHeader = substr($result , 0, $header_size);
   $responseBody   = substr($result , $header_size);

    echo 'Header: <br>'. $responseHeader;
    echo 'Body: <br>'. $responseBody;


curl_close($ch);

var_dump($ch);

var_dump($result);

but on :

var_dump($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

browser give  :

> Header: 
>   Body: resource(2) of type (Unknown)
>
> bool(false)

any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this option in curl and try , may it works for you

```
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

For more info refer [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)